# TextArea caret blink time?

Tags: javafx

I’m looking for a way to change the blink time of the caret in a `TextArea`. The closest thing I could find to what I’m after is:

```
-fx-display-caret: false;
```

But that turns off the caret completely. I’d simply like to make it blink faster than it already does—it seems a little slow to me.

I did a good long search here on *Stackoverflow*, but as always—should someone know a similar question that has already been answered, do mark this as a duplicate. Perhaps otherwise someone can point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** Twinkle twinkle little caret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use RichtTextFX from GitHub [link](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX)

It supports a `-fx-caret-blink-rate`, which can be set.

**Attention:** the newest version should be used because one hour ago a bug was solved: https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/issues/426

Comment: Whilst I’d rather stay away from 3rd party libraries I’m assuming your answer means there’s no easy way to do it in JavaFX—is that so?

Comment: JTextField is a Swing component, where modifying caret behavior is not really an issue, since it can be accessed via `getCaret()` method. As far as I know the same can't be done in JavaFX.

Comment: @Dth yeah you are right, i open the wrong project from me

Comment: @D.Ataro: Yes, rather than using a 3rd party library, there is no easy way. The blinking is implemented in the `private static final class CaretBlinking` inside `TextInputControlSkin` class with hardcoded values: 0.5 sec hidden carret then 1sec visible caret. So you could rewrite the skins otherwise.

Comment: It appears the RichTextFX [can’t be downloaded at the moment](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX#manual-download-1)—perhaps due to rich text no longer being supported by `TextArea` the project has been cancelled?

Comment: @D.Ataro the "fat JAR" can be downloaded and they are still developing, see graphs on github.